# How to get QField to show vector layer categorized styles as shown in my QGIS project

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am using QGIS 2.18 (on Windows 7) to create a QField project on an Android Samsung Galaxy Tab S.  In QGIS I have a line and point vector file and each have different colors set depending on an attribute values.  In the QGIS layers panel I can see the categories.  When I transfer my project and open it in QField I see the layer names but no attribute styles.  I can digitize a point or line and assign the new feature a name based on my categories. QField renders the new feature with the correct style and all but I need to see on the tablet what the line or point colors represent in the field.

How do I get QField to show the shapefile style categories?